# windows ce - 2d graphics library

Tags: windows-ce, 2d

I have Windows CE 5.0 device and it doesn't support any hardware accelearation.
I am looking for some good 2d graphics library to do following things.
I prefer backend programming in Compact .Net Framework.

- Drawing fonts with antialiasing.
- drawing lines, and simple vector objects with antialiasing.
- I am not doing animation, so i don't care about frames per seconds performance.

i have looked into following libraries, but nothing suits me.

- opengl (vincent 3d software rendering) - works, but api is very low level and complex.
- openvg - no software implementation for windows ce.
- Cairo - api is very neat, but no wince build.
- Adobe Flash - installs as browser plugin , no activex support in wince.

Comment: Wow... and how much did you pay for it?

Comment: And finally the question arrived.

Comment: sorry guys, pressed submit button accidentally , before typing question.

Answer (score 3):

Anti-aliased fonts in .Net CF 2.0+ can be done with Microsoft.WindowsCE.Form.LogFont -- after creating your logfont, you can use it with any WinForms widget's .Font property by converting it using System.Drawing.Font.FromLogFont().

...you might need to enable anti-aliasing in the registry for these to render properly, see this MSDN article for the right keys: `[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901096.aspx][1]`.

There was a decent implementation of GDI+ for .Net CF 1.0 called "XrossOne Mobile GDI+", it's not longer supported, but you can get the source code here: `http://www.isquaredsoftware.com/XrossOneGDIPlus.php` -- Run it through the import wizard on VS2008 to build it for later versions of CF. I liked this library for its alpha transparency support without hardware acceleration, rounded rectangles and gradient support.

Answer (score 0):

Someone was advertising this library in some forum. It's for Windows Mobile, but you can check it out. I have no experience with it.
[link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsmobiledev/thread/010d19fa-2d23-4039-b279-03fc9359fee7/)

Answer (score 0):

I have Google's skia library compiling under WindowsCE, although I haven't done much with it yet :) It wasn't too hard to get working. It does support a OpenGL/ES backend.

There is also AGG (Anti Grain Geometry) which is a heavy C++ library based on templates.

Comment: I cannot find any info about compiling skia under windowsce ; can you provide some info or the dll or how you build it? thanx